# What happens to log data in a Kafka compacted topic when the initial offset has been increased ahead of existing records?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I can't find it documented anywhere, but what does Kafka do with records that are no longer accessible?

I've found that I can produce records to a compacted topic on a v1.1 Kafka cluster, configure the topic for `cleanup.policy=delete`, and use the v1.1 [`AdminClient.deleteRecords()`](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#deleteRecords-java.util.Map-) method to "delete" records from the topic partitions, and finally restore the `cleanup.policy=compact` configuration.

What actually appears to be happening behind the scenes is rather than deleting records from log segments, Kafka is incrementing the initial offset for each partition to the value you supply with the deleteRecords method:

```
[2019-02-07 01:46:55,282] INFO [Log partition=delete-records-compact-topic-2, dir=/data/kafka] Incrementing log start offset to 505317 (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-07 01:46:55,295] INFO [Log partition=delete-records-compact-topic-1, dir=/data/kafka] Incrementing log start offset to 485663 (kafka.log.Log)
[2019-02-07 01:46:55,298] INFO [Log partition=delete-records-compact-topic-3, dir=/data/kafka] Incrementing log start offset to 478872 (kafka.log.Log)
```

New consumers will begin reading from those initial offsets, so the records are effectively deleted from their point of view, but the data in the log files is still there. Since the data on the log files isn't deleted by the `deleteRecords` API call, and the compact topic is not subject to retention, will the data in the log files be around forever until existing keys are updated and compaction takes place? Or will the log cleaner/scheduler eventually remove it since the records prior to the initial offset are no longer available to consumers?

I'm not exactly following a supported pattern since the AdminClient.deleteRecords method throws a PolicyViolationException if the topic is still configured with `cleanup.policy=compact`, but this method would be far simpler for me to use than a retention-based topic purge or topic delete/recreate method.

Comment: I would like to think the cleaner will remove all old segments, but it very well might skip over a topic directory that is set to a compacted setting...